# Bidirectional OneToMany assocation between sub and superclass not working (JPA with Hibernate 3.6.7)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, parent, bidirectional

I have two classes, Employee and Manager.  Manager extends Employee, as it is a type of employee.  Employee has an instance of Manager, which represents the idea of an employee having one manager.  Conversely, manager has a set of Employees.  There are two tables, EMPLOYEE and MANAGER:

```
table EMPLOYEE
  long ID
  varchar NAME
  long MANAGERID

table MANAGER
  long ID
  long EMPLOYEEID //a join on this field enables inheritance
```

The classes look like this:

Employee.java (setters and getters omitted for brevity):

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE", schema = "TEST01")
public class Employee extends hata.util.Entity implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)   
    protected Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MANAGERID")
    protected Manager manager;

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
    protected String firstname;
```

Manager.java

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEEID")
@Table(name = "MANAGER", schema = "TEST01")
public class Manager extends Employee implements java.io.Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "manager")
    private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>(0);
```

I have filled the tables with a few employees, and all of those employees have the same manager, except for one employee - the one who is the manager.  He himself has no manager.  (If you're following me correctly, then it should be obvious that I have 1 row in the manager table, with and EMPLOYEEID referring back to a row in the EMPLOYEE table that has null as it's MANAGERID).

So, this setup looked correct to me, however when I tried to query all Employee objects with:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select em from Employee em");
result = (List<Employee>) q.getResultList();
```

I get a nasty stack trace:

*Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of hata.staff.entity.Employee.manager
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectSetter.set(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:586)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3824)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:898)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:773)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2294)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2172)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2167)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:448)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:236)
    ... 108 more
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set hata.staff.entity.Manager field hata.staff.entity.Employee.manager to hata.staff.entity.Employee**
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:680)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectSetter.set(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:139)
    ... 124 more*

Did I code this wrong, or can hibernate simply not handle this scenario?  I'd appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `EMPLOYEEID` column in manager shouldn't be there. `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` means that the primary key is also the join column. So, the `ID` column in `MANAGER` is both the primary key and the foreign key to `EMPLOYEE`.

And the annotation should of course be changed to `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID")` (or it must be removed, since the default is to use the same column name as in the parent table)

See http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are a genius.  I fixed it according to your instructions, and it works perfectly now!